# c++ how to create public and protected accessors to same member

Tags: c++, public-method

In case I have two methods - one public, one protected that return the reference to same member, I get following compilation error:

```
'Server::getManager': cannot access protected member declared in class 'Server'
```

When I comment out protected function, code works. Could you please advise why this is happening?  Why the compiler cannot find the public function to same member?

```
class Manager
    {
    };

class Server
{
public:
    const Manager & getManager() const { return m_man; }
protected:
    Manager & getManager() { return m_man;  } // <-- after removing this method I get no compilation error

private:

    Manager m_man;
};

int main()
{

    Server s;
    const Manager& m = s.getManager();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler finds the public one, but the protected one is a better match. It matches exactly.

Comment: Why would you need the protected one if the public one returns the same thing?

Comment: Access specifiers are evaluated after overload resolution. So the compiler first finds the best match, and *then* checks if it's accessible. I suggest you simply rename the protected member, since you obviously intend to use it in a different context.

Comment: @wizzardmr42, because the class or it's derived classes may want to modify the manager **and** be const correct. Using an accessor function here as well, has the same benefit of being able to change the implementation without patching your entire code base.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why the compiler cannot find the public function to same member?

That's not the issue. The compiler finds *both* functions and performs overload resolution to determine which is the best viable candidate. The two candidates are:

```
Manager&       getManager()        // protected
Manager const& getManager() const  // public
```

For member functions, there is an implicit first object parameter that is the instance of the class itself. In this case, the two functions become:

```
getManager(Server& )         // protected
getManager(Server const& )   // public
```

We're invoking it on an object (`s`) that is not `const`. Both candidates are viable, but the `public` candidate takes a reference to a *more* *cv*-qualified object than the `protected` candidate - so it's less preferred. The standardese is in [over.ics.rank]:

> Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence
>   S2 if
>   — S1 and S2 are reference bindings (8.5.3), and the types to which the references refer are the same
>   type except for top-level cv-qualifiers, and the type to which the reference initialized by S2 refers
>   is more cv-qualified than the type to which the reference initialized by S1 refers.

As a result, the `protected` candidate is preferred - so that's the one that's called.

Unfortunately, it's `protected`, so calling it is ill-formed. The access control is checked after overload resolution. So you'll have to restructure your program somehow. You could simply cast `s` to `const`:

```
const Manager& m = const_cast<Server const&>(s).getManager();
```

This would make the `protected` candidate non-viable.

Comment: Alternatively call the protected one getWritableManager. You don't *have* to overload functions.